# Is .htacess protection enough?

Tags: security, .htaccess

Let's take a wordpress site as an example, as you guys know, wordpress' admin panel can be accessed only through site/wp-admin. My question is if I used .htaccess file to deny all access from other IPs except mine, will my site be safed from hackers?

Note: To keep things simple, let's assume that the site contains only static contents, with the contents retrieved from the database, IMHO if there's no input for the hackers than there's no way that the site can be hacked with XSS, sql injection, etc. Please correct me if I'm wrong even a wise man like me can be wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is useful for security, but it does not guarantee invulnerability from hackers, even with all of your assumptions. http://www.cmswire.com/cms/web-cms/how-they-hack-your-website-overview-of-common-techniques-002339.php

Answer (score 0):

Using `.htaccess` alone to restrict access to a URL by IP address is a "good enough" solution in that most of the time it will work just fine. There are certain pitfalls however, like if your IP address changes, you have to go into the console and update your `.htaccess` file, which isn't a huge deal but also inconvenient.

IMO you'd be better off focusing on using SSL (SSL certificates are cheaper than ever!) to encrypt all traffic to your site (or at least your admin panel), and choosing a strong admin password, than you would trying to restrict access to your admin panel from unknown locations.